# How does NPS Tier - 1 80CCD work?

Tags: income-tax, india, tax-deduction, pension-plan

**Conditions:**
NPS Tier-1 contribution from salary per year > 60000
NPS Tier-1 contribution from company per year > 60000

### Question 1:

How much amount is counted for 80CCD? Is it just salary or also the government contribution?

### Question 2:

Consider the following scenarios - 
Fixed amount is amount of NPS contribution.

**Scene 1:**
Invest in NPS for > Rs.60K.
Invest in PPF/ELSS/Insurance for Rs. 1.5 Lakhs 
You get Rs.2 Lakh tax benefit, rest 10K investment doesn't get any rebate.

**Scene 2:**
Invest in NPS for > Rs.60K.
Invest in PPF/ELSS/Insurance for Rs. 1.4 Lakhs 
You get Rs.2 Lakh tax benefit. Total NPS is utilised.

My question is whether scene 2 is possible or not? Do I have to invest in PPF/ELSS/Insurance or whatever 80C permits for full Rs. 1.5 Lakhs and only then I'd get to use  extra tax benefit of Rs. 50K or can I reduce my PPF/ELSS/Insurance to fit in NPS contributions?

Answer (score 0):

Only your contribution is counted towards 80CCD.

Both scene 1 and 2 are possible. You can choose based on convenience

Answer (score 0):

80CCD is just for NPS & its not mandatory to have utilized the 1.5 lakh limit you can still claim 80CCD.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

**How much amount is counted for 80CCD? Is it just salary or also the government contribution?**

- For non-govt. employee, there is no contribution by the government.
- The amount limits are: Self-contribution - 10% of salary [80CCD(1)] + Rs. 50,000 [80CCD(1B)]. Employer contribution: 10% of salary [80CCD(2)].

And total deduction limit of 1.5 lakh under section 80C, 80CCC, 80CCD(1) combined, and 50k under section 80CCD(1B).

**Question 2:**

Scenario 2 is possible. Rs. 1.5 lakh limit is for all deductions under section 80C, 80CCC & 80CCD(1). Here, 1.4 lakh is available u/s 80C, 10k in 80CCD(1) = 1.5 lakh & 50k in 80CCD(1B).